# I have a question about react array clearing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

There is an array in the parent class(TodolistActivity), and the child class(TaskCallFunc) displays the elements in the array. When I use a.list= []; to clear the array, there is no clearing on the page

but a.list.length = 0 is ok. why?

Here is my code:

```
interface IListData {
    list: IActivityData[]
}

interface IActivityData {
    id: number,
    content: string,
    finish: boolean
}

export function TodolistActivity(activty: IListData) {
    const [acty, setActivity] = useState(activty);
    const [content, setContent] = useState('');
    const input_ref = React.createRef<HTMLInputElement>();
    const [selectCount, setSelect] = useState(0);
    
    const handleAdd = () => {

        if (input_ref.current) {
            if (input_ref.current.value === '') {
                alert("输入内容 不能为空!");
                return;
            }
            let id = acty.list.length;
            acty.list.unshift({ id: id, content: content, finish: false })
            let a = { ...acty }
            setActivity(a);
            input_ref.current.value = "";
        }

    }

    const calcuateSelect = () => {
        let a = acty.list.filter((v, i) => { return v.finish === true })
        setSelect(a.length);
    }

    const handleChange = (input: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setContent(input.target.value);
    }

    const clearTask = () => {

        let a = { ...acty};
         a.list= [];
        //a.list.length = 0;
        setActivity(a);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input type='text' onChange={handleChange} ref={input_ref} />
            <button className="add task" onClick={handleAdd}>add task</button>
            <button className="clear task" onClick={clearTask}>clear task</button>
            {console.log(acty)}
            <TaskCallFunc data={acty} action={() => { calcuateSelect() }} />
            <br />
            <label htmlFor="">select{selectCount}/{acty.list.length}</label>
        </div>
    );
}

interface ItaskCell {
    data: IListData,
    action: () => void
}

function TaskCallFunc(taskData: ItaskCell) {
    const [data, setData] = useState(taskData);

    const HandleSlecet = (x: number) => {

        for (let index = 0; index < data.data.list.length; index++) {
            if (data.data.list[index].id === x) {
                let newState = { ...data };
                newState.data.list[index].finish = !data.data.list[index].finish;
                setData(newState);
                data.action();
            }
        }
    }
    const handleMap = () => {
        return data.data.list.map((v, i) => { return <li key={v.id}>{v.id}: {v.content} <input type="checkbox" checked={v.finish} onChange={() => { HandleSlecet(v.id) }} /> </li> });
    }

    return (
        <ul>{handleMap()}</ul>
    );
}
```

If you know the answer, please let me know thank you

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Write a title that **summarizes the specific problem**"_

Comment: I think because React don't see new value in your state., so they don't do re-render. If `activty` is an array so you can use `setActivity([])` I guess.

Comment: Careful with the `handleAdd` function in the parent, `acty.list.unshift(....)` is a state mutation! (*updates the array in-place*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TaskCallFunc` component doesn't "listen" for changes on the `taskData` prop to update the local copy stored in state. Use an `useEffect` hook with a dependency on `taskData` prop to update the state when it changes.

```
function TaskCallFunc(taskData: ItaskCell) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(taskData);

  useEffect(() => {
    setData(taskData);
  }, [taskData]);

  ...
```

Comment: What should I do if I use the form of a class component ‘ class TaskCell1 extends 
 React.Component<ItaskCell>
{
    state = { list: this.props.data.list, action: this.props.action }
    HandleSlecet = (x: number) => {...}
    handleMap = () => {
        return this.state.list.map((v, i) => {
            return <li key={v.id}>{v.id}: {v.content}
                <input type="checkbox" checked={v.finish} onChange={() => { 
                                this.HandleSlecet(v.id) }} /></li>
        });
    }
    render() {
        return <ul>{this.handleMap()}</ul>
    }
}'

Comment: @tongtian Class components have component lifecycle methods. `useEffect` with dependency array is roughly equivalent to both `componentDidMount` *and* `componentDidUpdate`. Since you *can* initialize state from props you would just need `componentDidUpdate` and you compare a previous props value to a current props value to issue a side-effect to update state.

Comment: @tongtian So I saw that you asked another question then deleted it. Still have an issue or is it all good for you?

Comment: @ Drew  At first I didn’t understand it and then I understood. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the array easely by doing setActivity({ list: [] }) consider also to add useEffect as Drew says to listen for changes

Comment: `activity` isn't an array, it's an object with a property that is an array, so `setActivity({ list: [] })` would be more correct. This is basically what OP does in the `clearTask` callback.

Comment: You are right Drew, i update the answer